# How to enable virtualization for the Acer Aspire 5738ZG?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtualization, acer, bios

I want to install windows on the virtualbox, but I have error like this :

```
VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Certain quests (e.g. OS/2 and QNX) require this feature and will fail to boot without it.
```

So, I read that I should set in BIOS, virtualization enable, but I don't have this option there, even I can't go to advanced option, nothing. What I should to do ? Update my BIOS, or maybe exists other way to do this ?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: You don't _need_ harware virtualization for Windows, it will just be quite slow.

Comment: As above. Also please read my answer. Your hardware is not recommended for running VMs but it doesn't mean you can't do it with OSes that can go without it (the vast majority). The error message gives two examples of OSes that require and I can't think of others. Nevertheless keep in mind Windows will run but it will be quite slow and there's nothing you can do to improve it.

Comment: If I "don't need harware virtualization for Windows" how to install it then? While I have error that its not allowing me to move forward?

Comment: Hummm... Just tested and apparently it is required for 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this [specifications](https://www.cnet.com/products/acer-aspire-5738zg-434g50mn-15-6-pentium-t4300-4-gb-ram-500-gb-hdd/specs/) your notebook has an `Intel Pentium T4300` CPU.

This CPU has no virtualization support and because of that such settings are absent in BIOS.

Please check the [Intel® Pentium® Processor T4300](http://ark.intel.com/products/37253/Intel-Pentium-Processor-T4300-1M-Cache-2_10-GHz-800-MHz-FSB) specifications. The relevant sepecification is quoted below:

**`Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x) ‡    No`**